# Does Highcharts 3.0.7 allow Highmaps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

The project already has highcharts.js 3.0.7 in use by many modules, If highmaps need to be introduced in the same application without updating the highcharts.js file. 
Is that possible?

Currently, I have updated both highcharts and highmaps to 4.2.4. Things are working fine.
Is it possible to make the maps work having the highcharts downgraded to 3.0.7?

Comment: I would only include highmaps.js on pages that require it. That way you could maintain "old" highcharts.js on pages that require it. But, if things are "working fine" after updating to 4.2.4 why bother?

Comment: But I have a page which has different charts among which one is the maps. Highcharts-more.js permits this having both highcharts and highmaps on the same page. Working fine, but there are some minor differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load Highmaps as a plugin for Highcharts, then earliest version of Highcharts you can use will be 4.0.1, because first release of Highmaps is 1.0.1.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L0q69gg7/1/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/4.0.1/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/1.0.1/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/4.0.1/modules/data.js"></script>
```

Comment: But, there is no way to introduce highmaps retaining Highcharts 3.0.7 right? There are minor difference in CSS if Highcharts is upgraded to 4.0.1. That is why, we are pressing 3.0.7.

Comment: @jeffrycopps There is a compatibility demo that is showing how to get old style (of version 3) in newer version (4) of Highcharts - http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Y5ak7/ (It is linked in [changelog](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog) )